# monte carlo tolerance simulation

Tags: python, montecarlo

I am new to work with Monte Carlo simulations and I am trying to find the best tolerance fit for 2 parts. The model should produce the probability of parts that would be in specification. It should be quite straightforward but I am not sure how to use the truncnorm.rvs:

```
n = 1000000 # number of trials

Component specifications
sigma = 3       # assume 99.7% of components in tolerance spec
dp = 3.900       # (Part Number 721634) diameter
tol_dpmax = 3.9015   # (Part Number 721634) diameter tolerance + (0.0015)
tol_dpmin = 3.9000   # 721634 diameter tolerance - (-0.0)
do = 3.900          # d ring diameter 
tol_domax = 3.90   # d ring diameter tolerance + (+0.0)
tol_domin = 3.8995   # d ring diameter tolerance - (-0.0005)

dp_std= (tol_dpmax-tol_dpmin/2/3)
do_std= (tol_domax-tol_domin/2/3)
def calculateInterference(dp, do):
    """
    in: diameters
    out: o ring interference 
    """
    
    interference = dp - do 
    return interference

def checkInterference(interference, lower, upper):
    """
    in: o ring interference
    out: Bool, T for pass, F for fail
    """
    
    if interference < lower or interference > upper:
        return False
    else:
        return True

# set interference limits
lower = 0.0 # smallest permissible interference 
upper = 0.0005 # largest permissible interference
      
interference_list = []  # initialize a list to store interference values per trial 
results = []            # initialize a list to store our trial results

# Main simulation loop
for trial in range(n):
    # Sample PDF for each component
   
    piston_sample = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_dpmin-dp)/sigma,(tol_dpmax-dp)/sigma)
    #piston_sample = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_dpmin-dp)/sigma,(tol_dpmax-dp)/sigma,dp,dp_std) #good one ish

    
    #oring_sample = np.random.normal(do, tol_domin/sigma)
    oring_sample = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_domin-do)/sigma,(tol_domax-do)/sigma)
    #oring_sample = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_domin-do)/sigma,(tol_domax-do)/sigma,do,do_std) #good one ish
    #cylinder_sample = np.random.normal(dc, tol_dc/sigma)
    
    # compute and store interference 
    interference = calculateInterference(piston_sample, oring_sample)
    interference_list.append(interference)
    
    # Trial check: log results of interference check
    results.append(checkInterference(interference, lower, upper))

# results check
goodAssemblyCount = sum(results)
failurePercentage =  100*((n - goodAssemblyCount) / n)
```

I will appreciate any help with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To sanity-check your use of `truncnorm` try generating a large number of samples and check their range:

```
sigma = 3
dp = 3.900
tol_dpmax = 3.9015
tol_dpmin = 3.9000

ntest = 10000
samp = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_dpmin-dp)/sigma,(tol_dpmax-dp)/sigma, size=ntest)
# scale & translate to original (non-normalized) location
samp_non_norm = (samp*sigma)+dp
print(f'minimum value: {samp_non_norm.min()}')
print(f'maximum value: {samp_non_norm.max()}')

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(samp_non_norm, 100)
```

[image]

From the histogram we see the truncation works as expected, but the distribution appears uniform.  This draws attention to the `sigma` parameter, the standard deviation off the process.  The comment

```
# assume 99.7% of components in tolerance spec
```

suggests `sigma = 3` is inconsistent with a tolerance range of 0.0015.  Consider re-centering the model at

```
dp_new = (tol_dpmin + tol_dpmax)/2
```

adjust the standard deviation so the one-sided range is three sigmas:

```
dp_std = (tol_dpmax - dp_new)/sigma  # top boundary is "three sigmas" from center
```

and re-model:

```
ntest = 10000
samp = scipy.stats.truncnorm.rvs((tol_dpmin-dp_new)/dp_std,(tol_dpmax-dp_new)/dp_std, size=ntest)
# scale & translate to original (non-normalized) location
samp_non_norm = (samp*dp_std)+dp_new
print(f'minimum value: {samp_non_norm.min()}')
print(f'maximum value: {samp_non_norm.max()}')

plt.hist(samp_non_norm, 100)
```

[image]

This looks much better!  It's a normal distribution with slight truncation at the lower and upper boundaries.

... and repeat this process to get the parameters for the d-ring model.